# How can I correctly reference private .NET 5 libraries?

Tags: c#, dll, nuget, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

For our new project we decided to use .NET 5 for compatibility and we chose to split the project into different libraries to maintain it easily.

The problems come out now that we are trying to put them together.

We would like to have a hierarchy of libraries where the middle level reference the low level ones and then in the main project reference the middle ones and automatically gains the references to the low levels. But this is not working as expected.

We started using direct reference to .dll differentiating by Debug and Release version for debugging as follows:

```
    <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <Reference Include="Model.Core">
        <HintPath>..\..\Model.Core\Model.Core\bin\Debug\net5.0\Model.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Services.Logging">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\Services\Services.Logging\Services.Logging\bin\Debug\net5.0\Services.Logging.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <Reference Include="Model.Core">
        <HintPath>..\..\Model.Core\Model.Core\bin\Release\net5.0\Model.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Services.Logging">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\Services\Services.Logging\Services.Logging\bin\Release\net5.0\Services.Logging.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

The problem with this approach is we don't get indirect references resolved (and them are not included inside the middle library) so when running a program we got a *FileNotFoundException* about the low level library.

Low-level libraries: Logger (wrapper for Serilog NuGet package), Model.Core
Middle-level library: Model.FileSystem
Running program

This is a call example:
Running program -> Model.FileSystem.ReadConfiguration() -> Logger.Log()

At this point we get the *FileNotFoundException*.

I know we can solve the problem by manually coping the necessary dlls directly inside the bin folder of running program but we would like to have it done automatically.

An alternative way can be to pack all libraries inside NuGet packages and then refer to them. This way references are automatically resolved but it seems over-complicated for our needs. I'm surely missing something but now this seems the procedure and it's quite painful while debugging:

1. Create the package with Debug configuration
2. Move the package to the local or private repository
3. Compile the project referencing the package
4. Debug
5. Once the debug ends, repeat 1, 2 and 3 with Release configuration version.

Imho this way there are too many manually parts needed each time we change something and could lead to problems mixing Debug and Release packages when forgetting about changing the package (can happen while compiling many many times).

I liked the direct reference where you can target Release and Debug versions of the same library according to main configuration but it doesn't work.

Sorry for being so verbose but it's quite complicated to explain this problem and I'm not sure I was clear. I asked this question even here [How to reference private library in debug/release mode](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5308910/How-to-reference-private-library-in-debug-release).

Thanks in advance to anyone tries to help me.

Comment: If the projects are in the same solution: project references would work fine here. If they're not: honestly, package references are still the option you want here, for transitive dependencies etc; that *can* be as simple as a network share, but other options are listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview

Comment: I think using a big solution will be my choice in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I have chosen to include in each solution the project needed for references. This way there are no missing libraries while running.

Not really what I wanted but it's the easiest way.